# Split on Vowels and Consonents (special requirement)

Tags: java, regex

My requirements to split a word, using regular expression:
1) split any number of vowels as one item in the beginning fo the word
2) any numbers of consonents as one item if followed by any numbers of vowels
3) if the end of word is a consonent then it should be appened to the previous tem
Example1: european ---> eu, ro, pean
Example2: anounce ---> a, nou, ce
Example3: anounc ---> a, nouc

Additional requirements
4) if a consonent is preceeded by @ then it is to be treated as a vowel
5) if a vowel is preceeded by @ then it is to be treated as a consonent
Example4: ano@nnc ---> a, no@nc (here @n is like a vowel, say o, similar to Example3)
Example5: anou@uc ---> a, nouc (here @u is like a consonent, say n, similar to Example3)

Thank you very much Andrey. for resolving first 3 questions

```
Arrays.toString(word.split("(?<=[aeiouAEIOU])"))
```

This does not give the intended output matcing the above requirements.

Comment: What output does it give?

Comment: Output: <br>
european  ---> [e, u, ro, pe, a, n]<br>
anounce  ---> [a, no, u, nce]<br>
anounc  ---> [a, no, u, nc]<br>

Comment: @send2kvd And maybe it would be also a good idea to move the wrong output into the question, not the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the job at least for the tree examples you've given:

```
word.split("(?i)(?<=[aeiou])(?=[^aeiou].*[aeiou])")
```

It checks that the previous character is a vowel, as in your attempt, but it also additionally checks that the next character is a consonant followed by at least one another vowel.

The `(?i)` switches into case-insensitive mode (Great thanks @Bohemian for the hint).

Example run:

```
european -> [eu,ro,pean]
anounce  -> [a,nou,nce]
anounc   -> [a,nounc]
```

Takeaway: length of the lookahead is not limited, it works with `.*`.

---

Here is a little demo as Scala script (uses same regex engine as Java):

```
for (word <- List(
  "european", "anounce", "anounc",
  "EUROPEAN", "Anounce", "AnOUnc")
) {
  val pieces = word.split("(?i)(?<=[aeiou])(?=[^aeiou].*[aeiou])")
  println("    " + word + " -> " + pieces.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
}
```

Output:

```
european -> [eu,ro,pean]
anounce -> [a,nou,nce]
anounc -> [a,nounc]
EUROPEAN -> [EU,RO,PEAN]
Anounce -> [A,nou,nce]
AnOUnc -> [A,nOUnc]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey.<br>
I have two more conditions:<br>
4) if a consonent is preceeded by @ then it is to be treated as a vowel<br>
5) if a vowel is preceeded by @ then it is to be treated as a consonent<br>
Example4: ann an@n ---> ann, an@n (here @n is like a vowel say a)<br>
Example5: ano@au ---> a, no, @au (here @a is like a consonent, say b)<br>

Comment: @send2kvd if this does what you expected, could you fix the examples in your question, so that others who try to solve a similar problem can understand the question better? There must be a little gray 'edit' button under your posting.

Comment: Consider researching the expression `(?i)`

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you for the advice! Never heard of this nice little feature, for some reason. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Bohemian & Andrey Tyukin: Thanks a lot